# how to pass customer_id from one window to another?

Tags: powerbuilder, powerbuilder-pfc

I have two windows w_customerorder and w_customerfree and the cusromerorder window has orderid which is identity column.now i want to pass this orderid to the customerfree window which has orderid column while its opening.can any one help me with this?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers. I flagged this question for closing.

Answer (score 0):

Do you open `w_customerfree` from `w_customerorder`?

Then you can use `openwithparm(w_customerfree, ll_orderid)`
and in the `w_customerfree` window you write `ll_orderid = Message.longparm` in the `open()` event.

Even if you don´t open `w_customerfree` from `w_customerorder` you can use the `Message.longparm` variable. Then you just fill it manually in `w_customerorder`

```
Message.longparm = ll_orderid
```

Comment: should i declare the ll_orderid in instance or global?

Comment: my guess is you can leave it as a local variable, because you store the orderid in the message object. Instance Variables are for one entire window and global variables are for the entire application. But could you be a little more clear on what exactly you are trying to do, because I am still a little struggling as of now. (see the question in my answer)

Comment: i need to open w_customerfree from w_customerorder.both these windows have the column orderid. now i need to pass the orderid from w_customerorder to w_customerfree?

Comment: Okay, then you can do it like I said. Whereever you open the window you do the following  long ll_orderid       ll_orderid = <however you get the orderid, getitemnumber probably>      openwithparm(w_customerfree, ll_orderid)          Then in w_customerfree in the open event you should get the orderid with long ll_orderid                      ll_orderid = Message.longparm

Comment: setting manually the `message` object is code smell. It can be easily broken by modifying the object hierarchy as the `message` object must be accessed at the very beginning of object open because it can be modified implicitly by following code. If the way to open the window cannot be changed by a `openwithparm()`, the parameter can be passed with a setter of the window before the open (instantiate it then open it)